# What File Types Should I Scan Before Opening?

Tags: malware, antivirus, infection-vector

In general, a person downloads some files from the Internet. Secure practice is to, at least, scan them before opening them.

In light of this, what file types (i.e. extensions) should a normal user (not analyzing malware) scan with a commercial antivirus before opening?

**Preferably** segmenting the answer per OS as:

**For Android: ANSWER**

**For Windows: ANSWER**

**For Linux: ANSWER**

Since, for example, .exe virus on Linux (even with Wine) isn't **that** dangerous.

**UPDATE**: Assume I'm using an online, signature-based scanner, not a local heuristics scanner. Local AVs auto scan everything already, this might have not been evident prior to this clarification.

Comment: "Secure practice is to" not download from any server and not without TLS (SSL)

Comment: @elsadek What does this have to do with scanning files?

Comment: "a person downloads some files from the Internet..."

Answer (score 10):

Everything.

You don't keep a dog and bark yourself; why install an AV software and second-guess what it should be doing? Sure, you can do a risk analysis against every individual file, but that sounds dull. Modern AV is fast, just scan everything. Let it worry about downloads.

Answer (score 4):

A few years ago people thought that jpegs were fine.

Then there was an exploit for a jpeg library.

You should be scanning everything. What might be safe today, won't necessarily be safe tomorrow. (In addition, keep your system up to date - this is much more important.)

Answer (score 3):

For an operating system-specific answer...

**On Linux: everything. Yes, even files ending in ".txt".**

Any file in Linux can have the executable bit set, and hence any file in Linux can act similarly to a .exe in Windows.

Moreover, Linux (or at least some flavours) doesn't check file extensions when deciding what program to use for opening a file; instead, it checks the first few bytes of a file's content. That means you can also hide a JPEG as "document.txt" - and JPEGs are *also* capable of transmitting viruses.

So, if you have a good antivirus program on Linux, why NOT scan every file that you download?

Comment: I don't. And I have to use online scanner, hence the question.